# Problems getting values from ifstream correctly

Tags: c++

**EDIT: I got it to work by changing the 'inStream >> next' to 'inStream >> skipws >> next'.  In one of my earlier functions (to pull the last and first name) I had toggled noskipws.  Apparently that toggle lasts between functions?

I have a program that is part of an assignment that is supposed to read a text file that is set up in the format of: "lastname firstname 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"  (where each of the 10 numbers are integer scores).

I am able to read in the lastname and firstname fine, but when I go to start reading in the numbers, I am only able to read in the first one and then all the rest get set to 0.

Below is the function that is supposed to read the scores in.  inStream has already had the lastname and firstname taken off.  The textfile I am using has one line:

Tosis Halley 85 23 10 95 43 12 59 43 20 77

When run the program and print out the student.score values from 0 to 9, the first one displays correctly as '85' but all the reset show as '0'.  Thoughts?

```
void GetScores (ifstream& inStream, record& student)
{
    int score[10] = {-1, -1, -1, -1 ,-1 ,-1 ,-1 ,-1 ,-1 ,-1};
    int next;
    int counter = 0;
    string test;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        inStream >> next;
        student.score[i] = next;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks correct to me. How do you print the values? (and what's the purpose of `counter`?)

Comment: Are you calling this function after reading firstname and lastname ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the local `score` array? You never read from it or write to it.

Comment: Check if the `inStream` is in error state after reading the first number (`inStream.good()` returns `true` if the `inStream` has no errors)

Comment: POW - Yes, I'm reading firstname/lastname in first.  The local score array was something I had been using to try and debug and just havent gotten it taken out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input is indeed all numbers, the function should actually work. However, you should **always** verify that inputs were indeed read correctly:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 10 && inStream >> next; ++i) {
    student.score[i] = next;
}
if (!inStream) {
    std::cout << "an input error occured\n";
}
```